# "The GNU C Programming Tutorial" bug

Tags: c

I was reading [**"The GNU C Programming Tutorial"**](http://www.crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/) and I think I caught a very small and subtle bug. It is on this [**chapter**](http://www.crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/Arrays-and-for-loops.html#Arrays%20and%20for%20loops). In `delete_multiples_of_prime(...)` function, in the `for` loop:

```
delete_multiples_of_prime (int prime)
{
  int index, multiplier = 2;

  for (index = prime * multiplier; index < ARRAY_SIZE; index = prime * multiplier++)
    sieve[index] = DELETED;
}
```

I think that the problem is in the increment part of the `for`. The author used the post-increment operator instead of the pre-increment one, with that in mind, I think that the loop will be executed with the initial index value twice.

Am I right?

Note: I'm pretty sure I'm right, and I wouldn't post this if I had found it somewhere else, but being there... It makes me doubt. Of course, I know that even if I am right, the performance difference is negligible.

Comment: Yes you seem to be right.

Comment: You're correct. It doesn't affect the correctness of the function because there's no harm in marking an element as deleted twice.

Comment: As an aside: this is not a good tutorial. It was originally written in 1987, and doesn't appear to have been updated to conform with modern C standards. (In particular, it's declaring functions with no return type, which is no longer permitted.) You really ought to find something more recent…

Comment: @duskwuff I know it is a little bit outdated (the lack of return type is not the first sign). However, I've been programming in C for a while now and I'm using it to review my C for a test (job interview). I searched for a while and it was the best I found that is free. Do you recommend me another one for this case (for a test and free or cheap in ebook/pdf format)?

Comment: I'd use a simpler loop still: `for (int index = prime * 2; index < ARRAY_SIZE; index += prime)`.  No need for so many multiplications.

Comment: Note that Jonathan Leffler's approach (1) eliminates the bug (2)  eliminates an unneeded variable AND  (3) is easier to understand, since it avoids reliance on side-effects, and is therefore easier to get right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that the loop is run twice for the first index.

However, this is not a *bug*, because assignment is an idempotent operation, so multiple assignments for a given index, will have no further effect or side effects. The function will always work the same, even if the first index is repeated twice.

Performancewise, the difference should be negligible, since it would only be one extra assignment per function call. (Because of idempotency it may also be simply optimized away by the compiler).

---

That being said, for clarity and in case the `for` loop body ever was changed to no longer be idempotent (for instance by adding a `printf` statement), I would personally use prefix increment:

```
for (index = prime * multiplier; index < ARRAY_SIZE; index = prime * ++multiplier)
```

Comment: Personally, I'd avoid using expressions (in this case) with side-effects in the first place.  The bug is insignificant in this case, as you say, but similar tricks (involving expressions with multiple effects and side effects) can cause significant bugs that are VERY difficult to track down.   And, in team settings the guilty party (the one who creates the problem) is often not the person who gets to "enjoy" finding and correcting it.